# JavaScript event callback function scope issue with this?

Tags: javascript

I am having a bit of a trouble understanding this concept. I have a loop in which I assign events and handlers to elements. The problem is that within my callback, I am also accessing a member function. I set the scope to get the correct `this` (referring to my object) but for `e.target`, I am not getting the correct element. So I guess I also want the correct element. Below is the code.

```
for(var i in type) {
    element.addEventListener(type[i].toLowerCase(), (function (_self, handler) { //Handle this reference in event callback  
        //Using a closure to return callback with correct context                   
        return function (event) {
            //console.log(arguments);
            //console.log(this);
            _self[handler].apply(_self, arguments);
        }
    }(this, type[i])), capture);
}
```

Now within my handler function:

```
dragStart: function (e) {
    console.log(e);
    var that = e.target,
        sectionName = that.id,
        interactionTarget = that.childNodes[0].alt;

    e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
    e.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', that.innerHTML);
    this.dragSrcEl = that;
    that.classList.add('fade');
    this.triggerEvent("whatever");
},
```

`triggerEvent` is a member function. What I want is the correct `this` corresponding to my object and also the correct element to which my event is bound.

Comment: With `_self[handler].apply(_self, this);`, seems like you'd want to do `_self[handler].call(_self, event);` instead, unless I'm missing something

Comment: Sorry, actually that was a leftover from debugging and struggling. I actually want to pass `arguments`

Comment: Hmm. In that case, shouldn't you be able to do `element.addEventListener(type[i].toLowerCase(), this[type[i]].bind(this)), capture)` instead? That should do what you want.

Comment: Yes that is another approach to do it. But the  main problem remains. Context has now changed to `object` and the `this` within the callback now refers to my object. But what about the element itself that without the binding we get when we use 'this`. How to access that. `e.target` is not what I want..that comes out to be the actual element clicked and not the one that has the listener.

Comment: Is e.srcElement what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you are asking now.  Here's how I might do it:

```
for(var i in type) {
    element.addEventListener(
        type[i].toLowerCase(), 
        this[type[i]].call(this, element), 
        capture)
}
```

And dragStart: (if using ES5)

```
dragStart: function (element) {
    return function(e){
        //this === original object
        //element === listening element
        //e.target === firing element
    }.bind(this)
}
```

If older IE needs to be supported:

```
dragStart: function (element) {
    var self = this
    return function(e){
        //self === original object
        //element === listening element
        //e.target === firing element
    }
}
```